# Python Get/convert values in nested list from dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert values in nested list from dict:

```py
list1 =  [["a","b"],["c"],["a","d"]]
dict1 = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
```

resultant_output

```py
new_list = [[1,2],[3],[1,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `list` comprehension, assuming the values of `list1` exist in `dict1`

```
new_list = [[dict1[v] for v in k] for k in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
res = [[dict1[i] for i in j] for j in list1]
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
[[1, 2], [3], [1, 4]]
```